# Chrome doesn't recognise gamepad

Tags: google-chrome, gamepad

For some reason Chrome doesn't recognise my gamepad, whereas Firefox does. I read something about "install a vaapi snap app of chrome", but I am not sure if this will fix the issue.

How can I get Chrome to recognise my gamepad (Xbox 360 controller connected to wireless receiver)?

Comment: It's supposed to work, can you check to see if a device /dev/input/js0 appears when the controller is connected?

Comment: I run the controller through jstest fine, so the computer picks it up, and so does firefox when I test it through html5 gamepad test.

Answer (score 0):

I's bug in package:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-bsu/+bug/1810057

Unfortunately packager doesn't seem to be interested.